# php 7.1 long path support not available for Windows Server 2008 r2 sp1- Apache is being restarted

Tags: apache, windows-server-2008-r2, php-7.1

I'm using Apache 2.4.29 (Win 64), Php 7.1.12. I'm unable to use php functions such as file_exists() for long file path (having length more than 259) Whereas it is feature of Php 7.1 which works fine with Windows 10.

Support must be in windows server 2008 r2 sp1 as it is not written anywhere that php 7.1 or Apache 2.4.29 (Win 64) don't support long file path feature for this window version. What am I missing?

Comment: Apache get restarted when I use file_exists() function(AH00428: Parent: child process 5360 exited with status 255)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The comment about Apache getting restarted seems to be critical to your question. Please edit it into your question, and delete the comment. If you think the crash is related to long paths, I would suggest filing a PHP bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my findings, the issue persists in php 7.1.12 but is fixed in 7.1.17.